# Storing a MongoDb result in a variable to run a Mocha test, getting undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

So, I'm trying to run a Mocha test, more precisely a Chakram test.
The problem is, I'm getting data from a collection in MongoDB and I want to store that data in a global variable to run some tests.
The problem is that inside the call back I get the data, but it doesn't set the global variables to run the tests.

Here is the code

```
var chakram = require('chakram'),
    expect = chakram.expect;

describe("Test", function() {
    var gl_email;
    var gl_token;

    before("Getting user data", function() {

        var setAccessData = function() {
            var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

            MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/virtusapp', function(err, db) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Connected to Database");
                var user = db.collection('users').findOne({
                    name: "virtus-app"
                });
                user.then(function(result) {
                    email = result.email;
                    token = result.token1 + result.token2;
                    db.close(test(email, token))
                });
            });
        }

        var test = function(email, token) {
            gl_email = email;
            gl_token = token;

            //Here the email and token are set, but it doesnt set the global variables

        }

        setAccessData();
    });

    it("should have set global email variable", function() {

        //here gl_email should be set, but I get UNDEFINED.

        expect(gl_email).to.eql("virtus-app@virtus.ufcg.edu.br");
    })
});
```

I believe that the problem is not with Chakram, because I haven't used in this code yet.

Comment: Yeah...the problem is more related to variable scope and async execution maybe....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `before` function is asynchronous. You should use a different signature to tell `mocha` that it has to wait until it's finished before running the tests.

```
before("Getting user data", function(done) {
...

    var test = function(email, token) {
        gl_email = email;
        gl_token = token;

        done();

    }
...
});
```

Only after `done()` is called the rest of the code is going to be executed by mocha.

Mocha docs has a very comprehensive guide on how to test asynchronous code https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code